# Show div after 10 secs and hide after 10 secs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transitions

I need to show a div (e.g. #mybox) in 10secs after page load, keep it visible for another 10 secs and then hide with a nice sliding in/out effects.

Thanks a lot for any hints/helps!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you google it first ? http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/   or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094419/chaining-jquery-animations

Comment: please show us what have you tried

Comment: you can try with `.delay(10000).show()` and `.delay(15000).hide()`

Comment: So, ten seconds or fifteen seconds? I am going to assume the description is correct, and fix the title.

Comment: Dont post questions like this, community will not support non research questions.

Answer (score 6):

Please use the below function:

```
cycle();
function cycle() {
     $('#myid')
    .delay(10000)
    .fadeIn(300)
    .delay(10000)
    .fadeOut(300, cycle);
}
```

If we don't need a loop, then just one line of code is needed:

```
$('#myid').delay(10000).fadeIn(300).delay(10000).fadeOut(300);
```

Comment: Nice one, but I'm afraid the intention was not to fade in an out repeatedly (easy fix)

Comment: Also, `function() {cycle()}` could be replaced with just `cycle`.

Comment: If we don't need to call the function recursively, then we don't need the "cycle" function call at the end 
(just ".fadeOut(10);" is enough).

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('ur_element').show(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('ur_element').hide()
      }, 10000)
    })
  }, 10000)
})
```

Comment: Have you tested it? The timing is wrong. For starters, the element will start appearing immediately, not after 10 seconds. You need to wrap the call to show in an anonymous function so that it won't be executed immediately. Fixed that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try something like this.

```
setTimeout(show_div, 10000);
setTimeout(hide_div, 20000);

funciton show_div(){
    $('#mybox').show();
}

funciton hide_div(){
    $('#mybox').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be this way: http://jsfiddle.net/EzvGD/2/

```
$(function(){ //-----------------when page loads fire the code below.
  $('#div').delay(10000).show('slow').promise().done(function(){
     $('#div').delay(10000).hide('slow')
  });
});
```

Comment: Where did the second delay go?

Comment: He wants to wait 10 seconds, show the div, wait another 10 seconds and hide the div.

Comment: You are right i just lost it. may be i should take some rest.

Answer (score 1):

Ok in the future it's best to show us what you have tried so we can all help to improve your code.

With out knowing what your dealing with I'll give you one of many way's to do it.

Using jQuery

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#div1').slideIn();
  setTimeout(function() {
     $('#div1').slideOut();    
  }, 10000);
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tzvemt4m/

```
$(".Mask").each(function() {
  var tempstr = this.innerText;
  var replacestr = this.innerText.replace(/./g, "*");
  $(this).mouseover(function() {
    this.innerText = tempstr;
  });
  $(this).mouseout(function() {
    var tempObj = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      tempObj.innerText = replacestr;
    }, 10000);
  });
  this.innerText = replacestr;
});
```